# probability of events occuring independently by chance

Tags: probability

I have data about genetic mutations in 100 people. Some genes only seem to carry a mutation if another gene on a different chromosome also carries a mutation. I think the 2 genes may have some common functionality but I need to consider that this could be a chance event.

```
 gene_A is mutated in 7 people
 gene_B is mutated in 25 people
 gene_A is never mutated unless gene_B is also mutated
```

what is the probability that this would happen by chance if we assume the 2 mutations are independent of each other? How would I work this out?

> P_gene_A = $\frac{7}{100}$
>
> P_gene_B = $\frac{25}{100}$

Would it just be $(\frac{7}{101.0}) * (\frac{25}{101.0})$ or is it more complicated than this?

Comment: If they are independent, then the probability that all $75$ people with the non-mutated B have a non-mutated A is $(1-p_A)^{75}\sim.004$, so I would agree this is improbable.

Comment: Ok thanks, so the method is: (1-PA)**(all_people*PB)

Comment: I used your data to get an estimate for $p_A$, the probability that a randomly selected person has a muted A.  As you point out, your data would suggest that $p_A=.07$.  Thus the probability that a randomly selected person does not have a mutated A is $1-p_A=.93$, so the probability that 75 randomly selected people all have non-mutated A is $.93^{75}\sim .004$.  As that is below any sensible confidence level, I think we can reject the hypothesis that those $75$ are an unbiased sample...hence we can safely reject the hypothesis that A and B mutations are independent.